# Tkinter: Draw a circle on a canvas without create_oval

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I want to draw point by point a circle so without *canvas.create_oval()* but using the formula *x^2 + y^2 = r*. The circle also has to be drawn inside of a square.

This is the code:

```
center = (maxx - ((maxx - minx) / 2), maxy - ((maxy - miny) / 2))
radius = ((maxx - minx) / 2 + (maxy - miny) / 2) / 2

for xc in range(0, x):
    for yc in range(0, y):
        if radius - 10 <= (xc - center[0]) ** 2 + (yc - center[1]) ** 2 <= radius + 10:
            canvas.create_oval(xc + 50, yc + 50, xc + 50, yc + 50)
```

- (maxx, maxy) and (minx, min) are used to draw the rectangle (using *canvas.create_rectangle*)
- x and y are the width and the heigth of the canvas
- *canvas.create_oval(xc + 50, yc + 50, xc + 50, yc + 50)* is used only to simulate the poin, because in tkinter does not exist something like *canvas.create_point*

The problem is that the circle that came out is completely different from what I expected. (Don't care about the hand drawn circle.

x = 400, y = 300, minx = 103, maxx = 269, miny = 62, maxy = 212, center = (186.0, 137.0), radius = 79.0

[image: photo]

As you can see the circle is really smaller and the center is not where I want?
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: '*What am I doing wrong??*' - To start with, you're calling `canvas.create_oval()`, despite your comment, "*I can't use `canvas.create_oval()`*". Can you call it or not? If not, why not?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to explain that. I use that create_oval only to simulate a point (in fact as you can see the circles drawn are 1 pixel large). I can't use use .create_oval to draw the main circle, not at all

Comment: I know you say to ignore the hand drawn circle, but where did it come from?  Hand drawn to show that that's roughly the desired result?  Also, that box is the result of `create_rectangle`, right?  Also, what code drew that point in the center?

Comment: Your code that calls `create_oval` looks wrong.  I could possibly understand making the circle have radius of 50, but then wouldn't you want `create_oval(xc-25, yc-25, xc+25, yc+25)`?  If you're going to set `x1` to `x2` and `y1` to `y2`, it should just be `create_oval(xc, yc, xc, yc)`.

Comment: The only other advice I have is basic debugging.  Before your for loops, print everything out: `print("x = {0}, y = {1}, minx = {2}, maxx = {3}, miny = {4}, maxy = {5}, center = {6}, radius = {7}".format(minx, maxx, miny, maxy, center, radius))`  (And post what prints into your question.)

Comment: So, the main target of this program is to check if the hand drawn circle is actually a circle. To check this, I want to draw two circles, one smaller than the one we want to check, and one bigger; and then check if every point of the hand drawn circle is inside of these two circles. I'm sure there are al lot of better and more efficent solutions xD but I'm trying to create something without any conceptual help.

Comment: However, I seriously don't knwo why I put "+50", "-50" ecc... probably I was trying to solvfind the solution in some way....now the circle is correctly centered, it's only smaller than I expect

Comment: To answer your remaning questions: Yeah, the rectangle is drawn by canvas.create_rectangle(); the center point is canvas.create_oval(center[0], center[1], center[0], center[1]); I've added your code in my main question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136287/discussion-between-scott-mermelstein-and-matteo-secco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a good discussion where I questioned all the inputs, but the input wasn't the problem.

Sadly, it took us this long to realize the issue was the formula.

It's not r = x^2 + y^2, it's r^2 = x^2 + y^2.

The appropriate loop would look like this:

```
r_squared = radius * radius
for xc in range(0, x):
    for yc in range(0, y):
       if r_squared - 10 <= (xc - center[0]) ** 2 + (yc - center[1]) ** 2 <= r_squared + 10:
           canvas.create_oval(xc, yc, xc, yc)
```